# laravel 5 sphinx search

Tags: laravel-5, sphinx

I am trying to use sphinx in laravel 5.2 using this library :https://github.com/sngrl/sphinxsearch

I have followed all the steps, changed the ports but I am getting this issue :
ErrorException in SphinxClient.php line 418:`Undefined offset: 1`

```
HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 1', '/var/www/html/test/vendor/gigablah/sphinxphp/src/Sphinx/SphinxClient.php', '418', array('errno' => '0', 'errstr' => '', 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => '5432', 'fp' => resource))
```

in SphinxClient.php line 418 at SphinxClient->connect() in SphinxClient.php line 1362

I am not sure if the connection set with sphinx is done. Your help will be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance
Harsh Sanghani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After find every where for the issue, I got some luck my combining 2-3 answers.

I have to make some changes in the vendor file :- `SphinxClient.php`

have to comment out the following code :-

```
/*
    list(, $v) = unpack('N*', fread($fp, 4));
    $v = (int) $v;
    if ($v < 1) {
        fclose($fp);
        $this->error = sprintf('expected searchd protocol version 1+, got version \'%d\'', $v);

        return false;
    }
*/
```

And add following code before the above commented code :-

```
$r=unpack ( "N*", fread ( $fp, 4 ) );
if(!isset($r[1])){
    fclose ( $fp );
    $this->_error = "connected to host, but returned data is not correct";
    return false;
}
```

Now I can not get that error and get the result using sphinx search